# Monitoring host disk usage inside a docker

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I want to create a docker img for monitoring a server.

I try to get host storage information ( free/used/total space ...)

So, I start the container with `privileged`

I try to 'mount' the `\dev` of the host into `/mnt/dev_host` in the container but seem didn't help ...

How can i achieve this ?

Edit:
I know this is possible, Instana.com and Sematext.com provide a monitoring agent that run in docker and get that kind of metric from the host ...

Comment: Docker is designed so that containers can't typically see details of the host; a container can't usually access the host's devices, filesystem, network interfaces, _etc._  The sort of monitoring tool you're describing is better run outside a container so it doesn't have to disable core Docker features.

Comment: https://checkmk.com

Comment: @DavidMaze Like the link provide by Facty, i already see multiple service that provide a docker agent that can monitoring the host... but how ?

Comment: @DavidMaze is right, you are misinterpreting intended use of docker. Docker is just light weight Virtual Private Server. It means you can run anything inside regardless docker hosts (you can apply same for VMWare, KVM, etc ..). What you need is robust monitoring system.... and it can run in docker too

Comment: Yes i know .... i use docker for running a webserver ( and other stuff ) for my monitoring tools ... i juste want to make something like `df` and see the host partion  from inside a docker...  ( i'm the docker hoster, so i can do anything on my docker ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i mount the `/` of my host in read-only in my docker and `df` return all partition list ...

PS: if someone know exatly why, and what is the minimum requirement for `df` to list partition of my host i take it !